# Providing lat/long AND title in iOS Maps URL seems to cause zoom level to be ignored

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, ios4

I'm writing an iOS app that shows a location in Maps upon a user action. I'd like to drop a pin with a description and zoom in to show map detail.

If I invoke Maps with the url http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-33.895851,151.18483+(Some+Description)&z=19 I get a pin with 'Some Description', but the zoom level is ignored. This *does* work on the Google Maps website.

If I use http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-33.895851,151.18483&z=19 the zoom works, but I get no pin.

I've tried a few combinations of `?q=`, `?ll=` and `?sll=`, but so far, nothing will change zoom *and* show a description.

Any clues?

---

Just so we're *really* clear, here are some screenshots. I want this to work on a real device (i.e. with iOS Maps). The simulator uses Google Maps through Safari.

Here's what I see with URL 1 (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-33.895851,151.18483+(Some+Description)&z=19"]];`)

[image: SS 1]

This is URL 2 (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-33.895851,151.18483&z=19"]];`):

[image: SS 2]

This is relikd's suggestion (`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?z=19&q=-33.895851,151.18483+(Some+Description)"]];`):

[image]

I want the image I see in screenshot 2, but with a pin and a description.

---

Thanks to phix23, it looks like `&z=` is always ignored, and I got lucky in that my examples with `&z=19` happened to zoom in a lot. So, I'll rephrase: how can I 'encourage' iOS maps to zoom in?

Comment: You are passing the URL to `openURL:` method of `UIApplication`, right?

Comment: the zoom parameter does not work for both URL's on iPad 2 with iOS 5.1

Comment: for me both links are working in Simulator. But you can try to move the zoom level before: `http://maps.google.com/maps?z=19&q=-33.895851,151.18483+(Some+Description)`

Comment: @phix23 Yes. I used ``[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];`` to open the URL. This part works as I expect. For the second URL on iPhone 4/iOS 5.1, I do get zoomed in correctly (though I'm building for iOS 4).

Comment: @relikd Tried that, but zoom is still ignored.

Comment: @IanHowson, in what context did you try relikd's answer.  i had success with that on my device.

Comment: I don't think it will will work with the URL.  Are you open to using MapKit instead?

Comment: The zoom in URL 2 does not really work, what you get is zoom level 16, not 19!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year down the track, I ported to the iOS Google Maps API and it does exactly what I want with no dramas. I set zoom level 18 and it does exactly that. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

It's looking like it is not supported. In the Apple documentation, it states:

> q= The query parameter. This parameter is treated as if it had been
>   typed into the query box by the user on the maps.google.com page. q=*
>   is not supported

Following this train of logic, you can't specify the zoom in the search input and therefore can't using the "q=" query string parameter.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. ``&z=`` is a separate parameter. Google Maps lets you specify both, and both are honoured.

Comment: My thinking is that the docs say that the "parameter is treated as if it had been typed into the query box by the user on the maps.google.com". In that case, lat, lng and description are supported in the query box, but zoom isn't. It's as if the maps app is just extracting the lat, lng and description and entering them in the query box and submitting the query based on that, hence zoom is ignored.

Comment: Except that URL 2 shows the ``&z=`` parameter working. It's a separate parameter. relikd's suggestion shows that it's not just being stuffed into the query field.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps for iOS uses **raster** tiles (I think .png files), so it snaps to a size that will have a discreet number of tiles on the screen.  Google does this to give the user the best possible image.  You will not be able to zoom in between; only the user can make precise zoom adjustments.

If you need your zoom level to be precise, you won't be able to use Google Maps to display your maps.  You'll need to switch to a mapping platform that offers **vector** images.  [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) is one option.  It has existing libraries to integrate with your iOS apps.  See, for example, [Route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) and [Cloud-Made](http://cloudmade.com).

(If you don't know much about **raster** vs. **vector**, see [What's the Difference Between Raster and Vector?](http://www.psprint.com/resources/printing-tips-and-techniques/general/difference-between-raster-vector.asp)

Finally, the [iOS 6 maps page on Apple.com](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios6/maps/) indicates that the new iOS 6 mapping service will be vector.  If you'd like to code for this you should sign up for the iOS developer program ($99/year) on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) so your app will be ready when it launches this fall.

Comment: Interesting stuff - but it doesn't explain why zoom works so long as I don't provide a pin title. I don't care too much about the exact zoom level, so I'll play around with a few different value.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's weird.  Just a glitch (unless it's intended) in Google's geometry math.  You could file a bug: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20API%20v3%20-%20Bug. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it with different query parameters and came to the conclusion that the z parameter is not used at all by the maps app. Instead only the query-string (q) is used to determine a reasonable map region. Example: If you search for 'china' you will get a very large region, which is always the same no matter what the value of z is.

For the geo coding a POST-request with the query string is sent to `http://www.google.com/glm/mmap`. It basically returns the location for the pin and a region + some metadata.

The protocol is binary so better use the official API for testing:

Example: http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=-33.895851,151.18483

This gives you some JSON data with the geocoded address including a map region specified by

```
"LatLonBox": {
    "north": -33.8944020,
    "south": -33.8971000,
    "east": 151.1860350,
    "west": 151.1833370
  }
```

This region is then used by the app to display the result.

However when you set a description in the query string you can get different results.
I'd recommend not to set the description at all, because the app tries to figure it out itself through geocoding.

As a workaround you can also show the map inside your own app using MapKit. Then you have full control over the zoom factor and pin annotations. Also consider opening the map in Safari, maybe use Bing maps instead of google maps.

The good news:

In the iOS 6 SDK there are new API's for opening the maps app and you can now specify a description and map region:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.895851,151.18483);
MKPlacemark* p = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem* item =  [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:p];
item.name = @"Some Description";
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05);
[item openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{ MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey : [NSValue valueWithMKCoordinateSpan:span] }];
```

Comment: My test results don't agree. ``&z=`` is very clearly supported by URL 2. I realise that Google does some magic to choose a supported zoom region, but the *only difference* between URLs 1 and 2 is the description, and they give obviously different zoom result. Using iOS 6 isn't a realistic option.

Comment: Have you tested with 2 URLs with the same q but different z? I haven't found a single example where z has a real influence in the result on my iPad. What do you get here http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-33.895851,151.18483&z=12

Comment: Interesting - I get the same as URL 2.